# Structured query language Join query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, syntax

I am new to SQL.Is this a correct join for multiple tables.

```
  select * from  [dbo].[Quotes] Q ,[dbo].[Invoices] I ,[dbo].[Receipts] R ,
[dbo].[QuoteLines] QL where QL.QuoteID = Q.ID AND I.QuoteID = Q.ID
    AND R.QuoteID = Q.ID AND QL.Amount = 336.47 and QL.TravelType = 'International' and QL.Type = 'Accommodation'
```

Comment: The query might run, but the bigger question is whether the output is what you really expect.  Is the output what you expect?

Answer (score 4):

Your question

> Is this a correct join for multiple tables

Should be answered with *No*... It *might* work as expected, but this way of joining is outdated for centuries.

Your approach names all tables comma separated. This would lead to a huge *cartesian* product, a combination of each row with each row. The following `WHERE` clause makes sure, that you will get the needed/related rows and columns only...

Not knowing your structure this is a blind flight, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select * 
from  [dbo].[Quotes] Q 
inner join [dbo].[QuoteLines] QL on Q.ID=QL.QuoteID 
inner join [dbo].[Invoices] I on I.QuoteID=Q.ID
inner join [dbo].[Receipts] R on R.QuoteID=Q.ID

where   QL.Amount = 336.47 
    and QL.TravelType = 'International' 
    and QL.[Type] = 'Accommodation';
```

You might want to change `inner` to `left` in cases, where not each row has a corresponding row on the other side.

Comment: *outdated for centuries* LOL :-)

Comment: It is clearly outdated as you say. All main db systems implements JOIN since 2001.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:- 
Select table1.ID ,table1.Name
from Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table1 .ID =Table2 .ID 
inner join Table3 on table2.ID=Table3 .ID
where table1.Name = Table3.Name
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.